# Stored procedure calling sp_send_dbmail

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, email, stored-procedures, cursor

I'm trying to create a stored procedure in SQL Server 2008 that sends emails, that were inserted into an outbound table. I'm using `sp_send_dbmail`. It's using a cursor to loop thru the outbound table. I also want to delete the records that contain the emails I've already sent.

The stored procedure seems to be locking the records. It won't let me do a select statement on the outbound table.

This is the basic code from the stored procedure - having problems posting it.

```
Declare EmailCursor Cursor FAST_FORWARD FOR
    select email_id, out_type, from_addr, to_addr,
      reply_addr, subject, letter_body from outbound_email_queue

set @email_prof = (select email_profile from system_file)

Open EmailCursor

Fetch Next from EmailCursor into @email_type, @from_add, @to_add,

     @reply_add, @Mysubject, @message

While @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 BEGIN

exec msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail

begin TRAN

     DELETE FROM OUTBOUND_EMAIL_QUEUE WHERE EMAIL_ID = @email_id
       if (@@error = 0)
          begin
             commit tran
          end
       else
          begin
             rollback tran
             select -1
          end

fetch next from emailcursor into.

end close emailcursor

deallocate emailcursor

end
```

Comment: Try adding a (NOLOCK) hint on the cursor query.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's tripping over the cursor.  Also, your transaction around just the delete statement is unnecessary because a single delete statement is an atomic transaction.  You can eliminate the cursor and use a try catch block to ensure that your record is removed only if email is sent successfully.

```
While 1=1
BEGIN
    select top 1 @email_id=email_id, @email_type=email_id, @from_add=from_addr, @to_add=to_addr, @reply_add=reply_addr, @Mysubject=subject, @message=letter_body
    from outbound_email_queue

    if @@ROWCOUNT = 0
        break

    begin TRAN

    begin try
        DELETE FROM outbound_email_queue WHERE EMAIL_ID = @email_id
        exec msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail @recipients=@to_add ... etc.
        commit tran
    end try
    begin catch
        rollback tran
        select -1
    end catch
END
```

This code will break the loop if an error is encountered or if it empties the outbound_email_queue table.